# Hibernate 4: How to dynamically manage tables in a db

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

This questions has been asked a few times, but most of the answers are a few years old so I'll post this hoping someone has figured out an answer.

Problem: We have a production live system that is currently working great with hibernate 4/jboss/etc. The problem is a few of our production sites are integrated with legacy systems that are using the same database, and creating data in new tables.

We've been given a requirement to action against these tables from our system. Unfortunately, the way these legacy systems work, I can't define a default entity type to match against these tables, and the table names/columns vary widely.

What I can do is find the name of the tables.

What I can't do is get hibernate to manage these tables like I want to. I've spent the last week looking for a solution, but the biggest problem I have is that the entity manager is immutable after instantiated.

Older stackoverflow questions:
[Adding Tables and Columns in Hibernate on The Fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809616/adding-tables-and-columns-in-hibernate-on-the-fly)

Has anyone have any hints on where I can possibly make this requirement achievable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "...the entity manager is immutable" - true, but do you have to use the SAME entity manager?

Comment: No, I don't need to use the same entity manager...but the tables would still be unknown at time of creation

Answer (score 0):

Here's an outline of a way that this could work.  Basically, you'd use Hibernate's reverse engineering tools to generate class files, then compile them on the fly, and then create a new Configuration with them and use that to generate a new EntityManager.

***Hibernate reverse engineering***

There's a set of [IDE and Ant tools](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/4.0.1.Final/en/hibernatetools/html_single) that Hibernate provides for reverse engineering and code generation which, among other thing, can generate code based on a database definition.  Generally, their expectation is that people are going to generate code/mapping files based on a database either once, or during the build.  What you want to do is generate those artifacts from your running program, which is definitely off-label usage.  I'd start with the  [Ant task](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/4.0.1.Final/en/hibernatetools/html_single/index.html#d0e4821).  End goal of this step is to have generated POJOs representing the contents of the tables in your database.

***In process compilation***

Now that you've got your Java files, you need to compile them.  See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842684/how-to-compile-run-java-program-in-another-java-program) for an example of using `Process` to run javac on your files.  If you compile them to your classpath, they'll be [available to your process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942536/is-the-java-classpath-final-after-jvm-startup).

***Build a new configuration***

Using the `ejb3=true` flag when you generated the POJOs, you should know be able to add them to a [`Configuration`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html) object already annotated.  I'm not sure what the best way will be for you to actually identify the newly generated classes so that you can [`.addAnnotatedClass()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#addAnnotatedClass%28java.lang.Class%29).  It may be best to capture output from the hbm2java, or perhaps to scan the output folder for the new Java files, or perhaps there's another way that your program can 'know' about the new entities.  In any case, you can then use that `Configuration` to create a new `EntityManager` that maps to your new database structures.